# Oracle error 923 when selecting hardcoded values for some columns in UNION ALL

Tags: oracle, self-join, union-all

I am facing oracle error 00923 while trying to retrieve hard coded values (`''`) in one of the sub-query that is a part of UNION ALL query.

```
select p.owner,
       p.exception_id,
       p.status,
       p.product_id,
       p.event_id
from exception p, exception c
where c.Parent_Id  = p.Exception_Id
   AND c.Owner_COID = p.Owner_COID
UNION ALL
select p.owner,
       p.exception_id,
       p.status,
       '',
        ''
from exception  p
and not exists (select * from bb_Exception c 
                 WHERE c.Parent_Id = p.Exception_Id);
```

Could some one please help me resolve the issue?.

Thanks

Comment: You have used "and" instead of "where" in the second query block!

Answer (score 0):

No WHERE clause in the second half of the UNION ALL !

```
from exception  p
and not exists (select * from b
```

should be

```
from exception  p
where not exists (select * from b
```

Once you fix that, if  `p.product_id`  or `p.event_id` are numeric (as might be expected with IDs) then you should get this exception:

```
ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
```

The solution in to use `null` rather than empty string. Oracle treats them as equivalent but `''` is a varchar2 datatype and `null` is not.

Comment: I made the changes accordingly. I still get the error ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected. I get the same error when I execute the second query seperately

Comment: Did you fix the WHERE clause after the UNION ALL statement?